# How to get response from web-site where is using console application?

Tags: php, cron, cmd

It is for windows only.

The main aim is to identify who does php-script run - browser or cron. Therefore I would like to get print of $_SERVER in console application and understand what is the difference.

May be someone knows how to identify request from cron.

Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can test `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. If it is not set it's via the CLI, otherwise it's a browser. That is:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
   echo "Browser!";
} else {
   echo "CLI!";
}
```

Comment: This assumes the cron is being run like "php -f /path/to/file.php." If that's not the case and the OP is instead doing something like "curl  uri," then HTTP_HOST will be set to the local IP of the server.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said via the CLI.

Comment: Thanks. BUt how do we know who run this script - our system or another one? It can be not only browser

Comment: OK. Is it possible to be web-address instead of "/path/to/file.php"?